# Json incomplete output

Tags: javascript, json

I just starting learning Javascript and trying to build an application at the same... I think it's a good way to learn. I'm using the book "JavaScript Web Applications" Alex MacCaw to help me out.

I'm stuck in the part where I'm supose to serialize some strings to Json. Where the result should be something like that:

```
{"7B2A9E8D...":"{"name":"document","picture":"pictures.jpg","id":"7B2A9E8D..."}"}
```

But this is just for testing purpose but it outputs only the id record and ignore the rest.

Here are the links to my code:

https://gist.github.com/2047336

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Put it like this:

```
{"7B2A9E8D...":{"name":"document","picture":"pictures.jpg","id":"7B2A9E8D..."}}
```

With {} you are starting an object...if you put "{}" it is a string...but since you have many double quotes inside that string, you have syntax error.

UPDATE:

The problem for me is that it is not clear what you wanted to achieve with such huge code which should just save object into array :) (so I don't know what part actually needs to be changed). If you want few quick hints, here they are:

you have this peace of code:

```
var Event = Model.create();
        Event.attributes ['name', 'picture'];
        var _event = Event.init({name: "document", picture: "images.jpg"});
        _event.save();
        var json = JSON.stringify(Event.records);
        document.write(json);
```

where you actually call init() with some parameter (some object)...but if you look at your "init" function back in the Model.js, it doesn't accept any parameters. So it would be good that you change your init function from this:

```
init: function(){ 
            var instance = Object.create(this.prototype);
            instance.parent = this;
            instance.init.apply(instance, arguments);
            return instance;
        },
```

into this:

```
init: function(args){ 
            var instance = Object.create(this.prototype);
            instance.parent = this;
            instance.init.apply(instance, arguments);
            jQuery.extend(instance, args);
            return instance;
        },
```

even after that, your `JSON.stringify` will print wrong values (only _id) because it is not able to serialize circular reference that exists in your javascript object. But your properties are there and can be used. You can check that out with changing your code from this:

```
var Event = Model.create();
        Event.attributes ['name', 'picture'];
        var _event = Event.init({name: "document", picture: "images.jpg"});
        _event.save();
        var json = JSON.stringify(Event.records);
        document.write(json);
```

into this:

```
var Event = Model.create();
        Event.attributes ['name', 'picture'];
        var _event = Event.init({name: "document", picture: "images.jpg"});
        _event.save();

        var json = JSON.stringify(Event.records);
        document.write(json);

        for(var k in Event.records)
            alert(Event.records[k]['picture']);
```

it will alert one nice "images.jpg" string for you, which means that your object, together with your properties, is saved and ready to use (json.stringify is just not able to tell you that).

I hope this helps in your learning efforts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer vucetica, but this is actually the output from the function 'JSON.stringify().'

Comment: To answer to your question what I want to achieve, I'm actually learning how to use the codes in the book to build an application... as simple as displaying a grid with night life events happening in a area... For now, I'm just testing, playing with code to see how I can make it happen. I will test your solution later today and let you know. Thanks again!